# How to handle clob column in iics/informatica cloud

Tags: informatica-cloud

I am trying to map data from my oracle database to flatfile. But as I have CLOB column in my source table, my synchronization job is failing with error "Internal error. The DTM process terminated unexpectedly. Contact Informatica Global Customer Support". But if I convert the CLOB using to_char and try, it's working.But it works only for data less than 4000 chanracters. I have data lot more than this size. Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check data type of said column in informatica ?have you tried using STRING or TEXT data type?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I no more need this as that project is suspended.